# Unable to click on Allow / Don't allow buttons on the Notifications alert which is displaying upon launching the app

Tags: typescript, appium, webdriver-io

Technologies using: Webdriverio,Typescript,Appium

I write script to click on the Allow button of the permission alert. But the alert still showing up and not dismissed.

```
const alert1 = await $("//android.widget.Button[@text='Allow']");
await alert1.click();
```

Getting the error as: RROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.insoft.mobile.nimo.alpha' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'com.insoft.mobile.nimo.MainActivity' or 'com.insoft.mobile.nimo.alpha.com.insoft.mobile.nimo.MainActivity' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting

Please suggest how to dismiss the alert

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'acceptAlert()' method instead of trying to click on alert by its CSS locator.
Try something like that:

```
await browser.url("/");
await browser.acceptAlert();
const alertText = await $("p#result")
await expect(alertText).toHaveText("You successfully clicked an alert")
```

To dismiss alert you could try to set some options in your capabilities:

```
'goog:chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 1,
            'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 1,
        }
    },
```